# Long.toString(long n) yields non-static access error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Using Long.toString(1234l) in AndroidStudio 0.9.3 gives an error of

> Non-static method 'toString()' cannot be referenced from a static context

This obviously is a bug in AndroidStudio/IntelliJ. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: If you're going to down vote a legit and well worded question, care to explain why?

Comment: Just tried the same code snippet in Eclipse, so can confirm that it's something with your IDE. I personally haven't worked with AndroidStudio/IntelliJ, but hopefully someone else has and knows how to fix it. Good luck!

Comment: Check your imports and make sure you are picking up `java.lang.Long`.  Just tried it in my install (version 0.9.3) with no problems.

Comment: java.lang.Long.toString(123l, 10); produces the same error.

Comment: you inspired me, i'm going to delete AS and my whole sdk folder and try again.

Comment: Best of luck!  It sounds like either a bad SDK setup or something.

Comment: a brand new install of everything fixed it. Thanks guys. You were helpful!